# SQLCMD :r <path> where path is a variable

Tags: sqlcmd

Does the SQLCMD command `:r` support non-constant literal paths?

For example:

```
setvar $(path1) '.\script.sql'
:r $(path1) -- SQL01260: A fatal parser error occurred: .
:r '$(path1)' -- SQL01260: A fatal parser error occurred: .
:r "$(path1)" -- SQL01260: A fatal parser error occurred: .
```

Answer (score 6):

> Does the SQLCMD command :r support
>   non-constant literal paths?

It does. You are defining your variable in a wrong way. Try:

```
:setvar path1 "script.sql"
:r $(path1)
```

See also [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Comment: is there a possibility like `:r $(path)\module_v$(milesone)\01_AlterScript.sql`

Answer (score 2):

Just posting this here as an example for others to save the time I just lost.

test_setvar.sql file contains the following

```
-- :r test_setvar.sql
:reset

:setvar Name "filename"
print '$(Name)'
-- :setvar OutName '$(Name)'  -- NO wont work
-- :out $(OutName).txt
:r $(Name).sql  -- filename.sql exists and prints "Hello World"
:out $(Name).txt  -- filename.txt is created  

go
:out stdout
```

Stated clearly [here](http://www.programmer.bz/Home/tabid/115/asp_net_sql/167/Variables-in-Sqlcmd-Setvar-and-r-commands.aspx).

Note:
Double quotes needed for multi-part strings and fields with :out 
For example

```
:out "string bit"$(field1)"string bit2"$(field2)
```

Single quotes wrapping wont work with :out for this.

But...
Double or single quote wrapping is needed within a query.

```
where col.name LIKE "%" + "$(SEARCH_STRING)" + "%"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the file VS lists in Error list but rather with the file you reference.

The syntax error should be searched for the file you reference. For your example .\script.sql