# SQL Data tools - Run post-deployment script with conditionals

Tags: sql-server, continuous-integration, sql-server-data-tools

I'm working with a Database Projecto to deploy databases using "Data pack"

I've set up a paramenter "client", so depending the client I'll run a different set of scripts.

I tried different options, but nothing worked.

I've checked out [Conditional logic in PostDeployment.sql script using SQLCMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151021/conditional-logic-in-postdeployment-sql-script-using-sqlcmd) but no luck

```
if '$(client)' = 'a' 
:r .\GeneralParams\s01.sql 
:r .\Clients\a\a01.sql 

GO

if '$(client)' = 'b'
:r .\GeneralParams\r01.sql
:r .\Clients\b\b01.sql
```

Inside every external scripts there are more than 1 GO 
When you see the output file to be executed, it´s compiling all external files into one.

Does anyone know a way to overcome this o a beautiful workaround

I tried this option:

```
if '$(client)' = 'a' 
:r .\GeneralParams\s01.sql 
if '$(client)' = 'a' 
:r .\Clients\a\a01.sql 

GO

if '$(client)' = 'b'
:r .\GeneralParams\r01.sql
if '$(client)' = 'b'
:r .\Clients\b\b01.sql
```

but r01 has more that 1 GO and exits the if clause

Comment: if the external file has only 1 GO the script works, but as I have multiple, the script execute some commands ignoring the IF clause

Comment: What worked for me, not as elegant as I wanted, is to put the if clauses on each external script

Answer (score 0):

the way I manage to implement this was doing individual if clauses inside each external file. It's not a pretty but it Worked. I've created an output clause to register all the crud changed made to the database.